# Returning an array with/without a function from a service. What's the difference?

Tags: angular, return, angular-services

What's the difference between retrieving an array from a service through a function, or without the function? Any performance changes/ key changes I should know about?

I understand that when there's a private array, it's meant to only be accessed in that file. However, this server had made the array of objects private and I can't quite figure out why that would be necessary in this case.

Server >>

```
private servers = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Productionserver',
      status: 'online'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Testserver',
      status: 'offline'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Devserver',
      status: 'offline'
    }
  ];

  getServers() {
    return this.servers;
  }
```

Then, in a component, the getServers() function was called so the array could be retrieved. Why is this whole process necessary? Wouldn't it just be simpler to make the array public?

Answer (score 0):

What if you make the array public and then decide to fetch your data from a HTTP endpoint? You will have to change every place in code where you used the array directly. It's for encapsulation.